# Prove that a holomorphic function with postive real part is constant

Tags: complex-analysis

> Suppose that $f$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb C$ and that $\Re(f(z))\ge 0$ for all $z$. Show that $f$ is constant. [Hint: consider $e^{−f(z)}$.]

My thoughts: If $\Re(f(z))\ge 0 $ holds, then $e^{−f(z)}$ is a bounded holomorphic function (do I need to prove this or is it obvious?) So then by Liouville's Theorem $e^{−f(z)}$ is constant.

But then I'm not sure how to rigorously go from this $\exp(−f(z))$ back to $f(z)$.

Could anyone help me piece this together please?

Thanks

Comment: If $e^{-f(z)}$ is constant, since it's nonzero, you can apply a branch of the logarithm defined in a neighbourhood of the value to it. At the point where you can invoke Liouville's theorem, it's a safe bet that all involved persons already know $\lvert e^w\rvert = e^{\Re w}$.

Comment: what's your notation in that last line?

Comment: The real part, it's what $\TeX$ gives you for `\Re`. I prefer $\operatorname{Re}$, but I was too lazy to type `\operatorname{Re}`.

Comment: thanks - how could i prove that $exp(−f(z))$ is bounded and holomorphic? I'm not familiar with $∣e^w∣=e^(Re(w))$

Comment: $|\exp(x+iy)|=|\exp(x)\exp(iy)|=|\exp(x)||\exp(iy)|=|\exp(x)|$.

Comment: by the way you can also accept answers, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 6):

If you can show that $e^{-f(z)}$ is constant, then: $\frac {d}{dz}e^{-f(z)}=e^{-f(z)}f'(z)=0$, so $f'(z)=0$ , and $f(z)$ is constant.

Answer (score 0):

A different approach(without using $e^{-f(z)}$):

We know that the real and imaginary parts of an analytic function are harmonic functions. By [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_function#Liouville's_theorem), we know that the real part of $f(z)$ is constant. Furthermore, we know that by [Cauchy-Riemann equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations) the imaginary part of $f(z)$ is also constant. Thus we conclude that $f(z)$ is constant.

Comment: [agjnkjljlkg][1]jjgljl [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lusin%27s_theorem#General_form